# How to use same submit for 2 HTML forms

Tags: java, html, servlets

I would like to ask how can I use the same submit for 2 the html forms in one page. I would like to have the same action for both of the forms and thus the same servlet to handle the reuqest.

```
   <form action = "add">
     Enter first number: <input type = "text" name = "num1"><br>
     Enter second number: <input type = "text" name ="num2"><br>
  </form>
  <br>
  <br>
   <form action = "add">
     Enter Third: <input type = "text" name = "num1"><br>
     Enter fourth: <input type = "text" name ="num2"><br>
     <input type = "submit"> 
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 You can to enter one hidden parameter like

```
<input type="hidden" name="fieldHidden" value="formOne/formTwo">
```

in the jsp file for each form.

On servlet you will pass value of parameter into new variable

```
String form = request.getParameter("fieldHidden");

if(form.equals("formOne"){ 
  //process create logic for form 1
}
else if(form.equals("formTwo")) {
  //process create logic for form 2
}
```

*for example :*
**in your jsp file :**

```
  <form action = "add">
     <input type="hidden" name="fieldHidden" value="formOne">
     Enter first number: <input type = "text" name = "num1"><br>
     Enter second number: <input type = "text" name ="num2"><br>
     <input type = "submit"> 
  </form>
  <br>
  <br>
  <form action = "add">
     <input type="hidden" name="fieldHidden" value="formTwo">
     Enter Third: <input type = "text" name = "num1"><br>
     Enter fourth: <input type = "text" name ="num2"><br>
     <input type = "submit"> 
  </form>
```

**On servlet you will pass value of parameter into new variable**

```
String form = request.getParameter("fieldHidden");

if(form.equals("formOne"){ 
  //process create logic for form 1
}
else if(form.equals("formTwo")) {
  //process create logic for form 2
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much :) could I have only one button for instance to handle both forms ?

Comment: @JohnLeo, this is a good question, No can't have only one button for instance to handle both forms.